# Parallel processing in Linq and foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, plinq, parallel.foreach

This is my code :

```
        int j;
        WebShopEntities data = new WebShopEntities();
        var db = data;
        var list =
        (from line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(MyHttpApplication.GetAppDataPath() + "677254_dp_articles.TXT").AsParallel()
         where line.EndsWith(";") && !((line.StartsWith("prom_erp_partno")))
         let parts = line.Split('\t')
         select new WebShop.dp_articles
         {
             prom_erp_partno = parts[0],
             prom_mfm_partno = parts[1],
             prol_name = parts[2],
             mfm_short_name = parts[3],
             prom_prfm_id=int.TryParse(parts[4],out j)?int.Parse(parts[4]):0,
             prol_lng_id=int.Parse(parts[5]),
             prol_variant=parts[6]??null,
             vpl=parts[7]??null,
             status=parts[8],
             gross_weight=Decimal.Parse('0'+parts[9].Replace('.',',')),
             commodity_code=parts[10],
             returnable = parts[11].Replace(';', ' ').Trim()

         }).ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(list, item =>
         {

             if (!(from x in db.dp_articles.AsParallel() where x.prom_erp_partno == item.prom_erp_partno select x).Any())
             {

                 db.dp_articles.Add(new dp_articles
                 {
                     prom_erp_partno = item.prom_erp_partno,
                     prom_mfm_partno = item.prom_mfm_partno,
                     prol_name = item.prol_name,
                     mfm_short_name = item.mfm_short_name,
                     prom_prfm_id = item.prom_prfm_id,
                     prol_lng_id = item.prol_lng_id,
                     prol_variant = item.prol_variant,
                     vpl = item.vpl,
                     status = item.status,
                     gross_weight = item.gross_weight,
                     commodity_code = item.commodity_code,
                     returnable = item.returnable

                 });
             }
             else
             {

                 var itemU = db.dp_articles.Find(item.prom_erp_partno);
                 itemU.prom_mfm_partno = item.prom_mfm_partno;
                 itemU.prol_name = item.prol_name;
                 itemU.mfm_short_name = item.mfm_short_name;
                 itemU.prom_prfm_id = item.prom_prfm_id;
                 itemU.prol_lng_id = item.prol_lng_id;
                 itemU.prol_variant = item.prol_variant;
                 itemU.vpl = item.vpl;
                 itemU.status = item.status;
                 itemU.gross_weight = item.gross_weight;
                 itemU.commodity_code = item.commodity_code;
                 itemU.returnable = item.returnable;
             }

             db.SaveChanges();
         });
```

I need to do these process in parallel but I dont have any information about paralleling processes in c#.
After a quick search in Google I find these paralleling syntax but after I run it this error was appear :

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

and the stack trace :

> [InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.]
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +797
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
>      System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedDataSource`1.InitializePartitions(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 partitionCount, Boolean useStriping) +501
>      System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedDataSource`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 partitionCount, Boolean useStriping) +92
>      System.Linq.Parallel.ExchangeUtilities.PartitionDataSource(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 partitionCount, Boolean useStriping) +277
>      System.Linq.Parallel.ScanEnumerableQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient) +92
>      System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient) +578
>      System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient) +441
>      System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings) +386
>      System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.OpenQuery() +218
>      System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +32
>      System.Linq.Parallel.AnyAllSearchOperator`1.Aggregate() +64
>      System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Any(ParallelQuery`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +92
>      System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Any(ParallelQuery`1 source) +126
>      WebShop.Models.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<ArticlesParser>b__4b(dp_articles item) in    c:\Users\Ahmad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebShop\WebShop\Models\Ftp.cs:369
>      System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass2d`2.b__23(Int32 i) +63
>      System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c() +910
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() +72
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask) +17
>      System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0) +198
>   [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3834425
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +10919077
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() +10
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally) +925
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker(IList`1 list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally) +223
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker(IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally) +10893169
>      System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body) +110
>      WebShop.Models.Ftp.ArticlesParser() in c:\Users\Ahmad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebShop\WebShop\Models\Ftp.cs:366
>      webshop.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\Ahmad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebShop\WebShop\Controllers\HomeController.cs:46
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e() +225
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19() +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

This code parse a text file and tries to put it on a database or update it if existed.

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: localhost asp.net mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you are using EF concurrently from many threads. That is not allowed. Scan all of your code and make sure you have not a single place where you are using the same EF ObjectContext (etc.) from multiple threads.

Probably, you should create one context per thread or per unit of work.

Comment: Can you explain for me more ?

Comment: Sure, ask me something specific. On Stack Overflow it is expected that you do basic research yourself and ask when you're stuck.

Comment: I am using this property for my data context :
 '[ThreadStatic]
 static WebShopEntities data = new WebShopEntities();' 
and I removed the 'var db = data;'
the data context thread safe error was gone but the Object reference not set to an instance of an object appear.
How can I solve this ?
When I used break point after entered in parallel foreach loop,my database reference was gone null!!!

Comment: Did you initialize the ThreadStatic variable on all threads or just on one?

Comment: I initialized it in the part of the class properties :

`namespace WebShop.Models
{
    public class Ftp
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        static WebShopEntities data = new WebShopEntities();  ....`

Comment: You don't fully understand how ThreadStatic works. Reads the docs.

Comment: I initialized it by this code :
`[ThreadStatic]private static WebShopEntities _data;public static WebShopEntities data{get{if (_data == null){_data = new WebShopEntities();}return _data;}}`

but after it wants to save it on database this error was appear :
`Parameter value '250000,000' is out of range.`

Comment: Do you think that error message has something to do with ThreadStatic? What do you think it means?

Comment: no that is a problem with my decimal value in database.

Answer (score 2):

That error generally occurs if you try to use a list item before the entire result set has been enumerated (and is usually solved by a .AsEnumerable() or .ToList() at the end of the query in question)

In your case though I'd alter the line:

```
if (!(from x in db.dp_articles.AsParallel() where x.prom_erp_partno == item.prom_erp_partno select x).Any())
```

and remove the `.AsParallel()` . 
It serves no useful purpose as far as I can tell, and is probably blocking the inner bit of code, because trying to add to db.dp_articles whilst other threads are still querying it would be unsafe.

**EDIT**

Also remove the .AsParallel() from this line:

```
var list =
        (from line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(MyHttpApplication.GetAppDataPath() + "677254_dp_articles.TXT").AsParallel()
```

for every line of the file you are creating a parallel thread that filters it into the same list!

Comment: When I change the code to :
if ((from x in db.dp_articles where x.prom_erp_partno == item.prom_erp_partno select x).ToList().Count==0)
It says :
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I removed that but it says again :
The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: move the db.SaveChanges out of the Parallel bit.

Comment: I have changed it.Nothing is changed

Comment: Ok, reading a bit more it seems that you can't use a dataContext in multiple threads because it is not thread-safe. If you are determined to have parallel insert/updates you'll have to either create a datacontext in every thread, or revert to direct SQL queries. To be honest I'd probably abandon parallel processing altogether unless it's hideously slow.